Unable to update log level configurations for a spring boot application
The application is hosted in cloud foundry and when I try to update the log level configuration of the application using the actuators api --> /actuators/loggers/ROOT, response is 204. But after few seconds, log configurations gets reset to default, i.e. INFO
I am trying to update the log configuration to ERROR. Default is INFO. There are no errors.

Check if you are using the logback.xml file for logger configuration.
In logback.xml configuration file there an attribute to scan the configuration and set it along with the scan period.
You can try disabling the scan in this configuration. Default scan period is 60 seconds.
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="15 seconds">

